# Python how to square on input list? Ex: input: 7, output: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]

Tags: python

i'm trying to write a function where user can input a list of numbers, and then each number gets squared based on range 0 to n. For example, i want to input 7 and then the output is in range 0 to 7 is all square

```
number = []
n = int(input('input number: '))
for i in range(0, n):
    n.append(i**2)
print(n)
```

Comment: change `n.append` to `number.append`

Comment: …and also `print(number)` if you want to print the list.

Comment: You could do away with the list altogether and `print` inside the loop.

Comment: Also, note that `range(n)` will only do values 0 to n-1. You probably want `range(n+1)`

Answer (score 3):

a list comprehension is a great way to accomplish this in a fairly compact bit of code. https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/

```
n = int(input('input number: '))

squares = [x*x for x in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are quite good for this situation.

```
number = [entry**2 for entry in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python one-liner :)

```
vals=list(map(lambda x:int(x)**2,input().split()))
print(vals)
```

Here is the output: [0,1,4,9,16,..]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
number = []
for i in range(8):
    number.append(int(input('input number: '))**2)
print(number)
```